# Fetching Grouped Checkbox in a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a checkbox group in a view.

```
name = "group";
```

I want to iterate throug this group of checkboxes but I need to find a way to fetch them together;

All selected checkboxes are being posted with their values.

Would I be able to do something like this (one straight statement):

```
string[] name = Request.QueryString('group');

foreach(string value in name) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes are not returned on your query string but rather POSTed to your controller.

Only the selected checkbox values will be returned. To retrieve the entire list of possible checkbox values, you will need to reassemble those from your source.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.tags)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Tag" value="@item.TagID"
        @if (item.Selected) { <text>checked="checked"</text> }
        />
        @item.Name
    </label>
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult MyAction(IEnumerable<int> Tag)
{


}
```

Comment: @Dmitry don't edit someone's answer for substance. Post a comment and let andleer decide whether he wants to incorporate that edit or not.

Comment: sounds good. Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure why my suggestion is being rejected

Comment: andleer, the `name` attribute of the input should be equal to the parameter passed to the ActionResult so that ModelBinder actually binds them.

Comment: I haven't used the CheckBoxListFor helper but I think it is rather mute. The question was about how to retrieve the resulting selected items. Both the CheckBoxListFor and my answer return only the checked tags and from a controller standpoint, they are the same.

It is even possible that the list of items is static and coded as static HTML. Seems like a minor difference.

Comment: @Dmitry Fixed. The result of coping code from a project and then changing names. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

andleer's solution will work (with a minor adjustment that I made to his answer and that needs to be approved). However, there is a better way to handle list of checkboxes.
Please see [CheckBoxList(For) extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension)